How do I change the avatar icon color on hover in flutter ChoiceChip
I have a ListView of ChoiceChips and I want to change the color of the avatar and labelText on hover. I can change the color of the labelText but cannot for the avatar.
Example
I would like to match the avatar color to the labelText on hover. How can I do that?
I tried adding MaterialState on avatar similar to labelStyle but since the Icon is a custom object I don't believe that would work.
ChoiceChip(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 12.0),
      avatar: ParkIcons.activity(widget.activity,
          color: WidgetStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
        if (states.contains(WidgetState.hovered)) {
          print("avatar hover");
          return Colors.red;
          return theme.colorScheme.onSurface;
        }
        return foregroundColor;
      })),
      label: Text(widget.activity.displayName),
      labelStyle: theme.textTheme.labelLarge?.copyWith(
          color: WidgetStateColor.resolveWith((states) {
        if (states.contains(WidgetState.hovered)) {
          print("label hover");
          return Colors.red;
          return theme.colorScheme.onSurface;
        }
        return foregroundColor;
      })),
...
);

